# How to printf text with spaces as same line

Tags: linux, shell, loops, awk, printf

i have text file like this

```
B.10967 2020-09-09 12:01:58.913
B.10966 2020-09-09 12:01:51.670
B.10965 2020-09-09 12:01:24.070
```

and then i have some shell script for loop and then printf from loop results

```
pathlastsfcola="/media/LastPatch.txt";
for codes in $(cat $pathlastsfcola | tr -d '\r')
do
   printf "${codes}\n"
done;
```

and then results from loop is like this

```
B.10967
2020-09-09
12:01:58.913
B.10966
2020-09-09 
12:01:51.670
B.10965 
2020-09-09 
12:01:24.070
```

my expectation results is still like this

```
=================================
|code   | date time             |
=================================
|B.10967|2020-09-09 12:01:58.913|
|B.10966|2020-09-09 12:01:51.670|
|B.10965|2020-09-09 12:01:24.070|
=================================
```

how printf each data with spaces as separator

Comment: Sorry if I have missed something here but your sample input and sample expected output are looking same, could you please elaborate more on it.

Comment: sorry i mean i need print each data with spaces as separator
like first line with 3 columns

Comment: See. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
input="/media/LastPatch.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  printf "$line\n"
done < "$input"
```

I tried it on ubuntu and it works

I got that example from here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-howto-read-line-by-line-from-file/

Comment: Don't do `printf "$line\n"`, do `printf '%s\n' "$line"` instead. The former will fail when `$line` contains printf formatting chars, etc. You shouldn't be using a shell loop for this at all though as even in the best case it'll be extremely slow.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, written an tested with GNU `awk` in shown samples.

```
awk -v header_footer="=================================" '
BEGIN{
  OFS="|"
  print header_footer ORS "|code   | date time             |"
}
{
  print "",substr($0,1,length($1)),substr($0,length($1)+2),""
}
END{
  print header_footer
}' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
=================================
|code   | date time             |
|B.10967|2020-09-09 12:01:58.913|
|B.10966|2020-09-09 12:01:51.670|
|B.10965|2020-09-09 12:01:24.070|
=================================
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is just quote your variable, like I've shown below. All that has happened is that `$pathlastsfcola` has become `"$pathlastsfcola"`

```
for codes in "$pathlastsfcola"
do
   printf "${codes}\n"
done;
```

For an explanation check here:

https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html

Comment: No, that would print the name of the input file. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63806328/how-to-printf-text-with-spaces-as-same-line#comment112838724_63806497

Comment: True. I assumed that `pathlastsfcola=$( cat "/media/LastPatch.txt" );` was what the author meant. Should have probably checked before responding.